# Why won't my while loop break in Tictactoe?

Tags: python, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

I am writing code to a basic tictactoe game, but I am having trouble with a certain part of my code when trying to get it to break out of the while loop.

I have a list (= board) that contains 10 items = '*space*'. The fullBoardCheck function should return a boolean = True when the condition is met, otherwise False.

Within initializeGame, the while loop is set to continue while gameStatus = False. However, once I run the game and fill out 9 spaces of the Board, gameStatus changes to True but it does not break out of the  loop.

I cannot find what I am missing, and would appreciate any help you could offer.

Thanks

```
def placeMarkerO(board, position):
    board[position] = 'O'
    return board

def takeTurnO(board):
    print("It's O's turn!")
    wantedPosition = int(input('O, where would you like to go? (1-9): '))
    while not spaceCheck(board, wantedPosition):
        wantedPosition = int(input('This space is taken. Please choose an EMPTY space: '))
    return wantedPosition

def fullBoardCheck(board):
    # Returns true or false boolean checking if board is full
    return len([x for x in board if x == " "]) == 1

def initializeGame():
    board = [' '] * 10

    gameStatus = False

    while gameStatus == False:
        drawBoard(board)
        gameStatus = fullBoardCheck(board)
        position = takeTurnX(board)
        placeMarkerX(board, position)

        drawBoard(board)
        fullBoardCheck(board)
        position = takeTurnO(board)
        placeMarkerO(board, position)
```

Comment: Try to print the board in `fullBoardCheck` before the return statement. Then post the output of the board from where you think it should return true.

Comment: can you provide the code for `placeMarkerO`?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I added it to the top of the original post.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I added a print(fullBoardCheck(board)) before each gameStatus within the while loop. When I have added the 9th element into the board, the boolean changes from False to True, but it still does not break the while loop.

Comment: @struct_python what happens on the next loop? the condition only gets checked between each run of the loop

Comment: How do you know `gameStatus` changes to True? How do you verify it? Also, if you're debugging it, what happens next? Does it stay True?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I managed to fix it! It was because the boolean was becoming True after X's turn, and the while loop has to continue through to the end where it would ask for another O turn. So I simply added an if statement before the O's turn to check if gameStatus == False still, else I break the loop. Thank you!

Comment: You could also just check that it was `<= 1`

Comment: Tic Tac Toe boards have 9 spaces, why 10?  `board = [' '] *9`  `def fullBoardCheck(board):`  `return ' ' in board`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the  `fullBoardCheck` function:

```
def fullBoardCheck(board):
    return len([x for x in board if x == ' ']) == 0
```

You checked if the `len([x for x in board if x == ' ']) == 1`, 
however, you need to check if the length is 0 because you want to return whether the board is completely full.
Good Luck!